# Adding plugins to ckeditor while using rails_admin

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor, rails-admin

I've been banging my head against the wall on this for a few hours. Maybe someone can help me.

I've got a rails app. I'm using the rails_admin gem, version 0.6.2.

Following the rails_admin instructions, I enabled ckeditor on a few text fields, and it's working great.

Next I needed to customize some of the toolbar icons, so I created a custom `config.js` file in `app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/`

This works fine, I can change the toolbar buttons (example code from `config.js` is below)

```
CKEDITOR.config.toolbar_Custom = [
  { name: 'document',    items : [ 'Source','NewPage','Preview','-','Templates' ] }
  // other toolbars removed for brevity
];
CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = 'Custom';
```

Now I want to add some ckeditor plugins - specifically, the [codesnippet plugin.](http://ckeditor.com/addon/codesnippet)

I put the plugin files in `app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/plugins` and include them like so:

```
CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'codesnippet'
```

Now ckeditor won't load, console is complaining that **CKEDITOR.editor** and **CKEDITOR.style** are undefined. These errors are coming from the plugin js files, so I know they're being loaded, but they seem to be referenced before ckeditor has time to initialize?

I've tried wrapping up my config settings in something like

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(){
    // initialize config stuff here
});
```

But that does nothing.

I *think* the problem involves line 159 of [this coffeescript file from rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/4e2ef25dc8b0fe2519b8fc459174d927b57459a7/app/assets/javascripts/rails_admin/ra.widgets.coffee), it's setting up the editors and applying settings. But for the life of me, I'm lost, and the documentation has only confused me. Any help or hints appreciated.

Comment: whats the version of ckeditor and have you found a solution already since you posted the question? :D

Comment: @jaak-kütt, I ended up including CKEDITOR outside of the asset pipeline and without using the built-in rails_admin helpers. It was the only way I could reliably get it to load with some custom config options. I placed it in a directory `public/sharedassets/ckeditor`, added that to my precompile config in application.rb like so: `config.assets.precompile += %w( public/sharedassets/* )` and then included it in my application layout with a plain old <script> tag. It probably isn't the best for performance, but now at least I have visibility into how and from where it's being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Add below content into `config.js` file which will be at `app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/`.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
  config.extraPlugins = 'widget,dialog,codesnippet,widgetselection,lineutils';
}
```

Download the plugins (as zip) from below links. Extract them and put at `app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/plugins` which is required for codesnippet.

1. https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/widgetselection
2. https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/lineutils
3. https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/dialog
4. https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/widget
5. https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/codesnippet

Add below line into `assets.rb`.

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/* )
```

Enable it for rails_admin, try below for any specific model.

```
config.model 'Problem' do
    # Your code here
    edit do
      field :code_snippet, :ck_editor
      # Rest columns
    end
  end
```